# Can SBAR be the first tag of a sentence?

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees

I am new to parse trees, and if I understand correctly, SBAR indicates the beginning of a subordinate clause.

From Penn Treebank II Tags:

> SBAR - Clause introduced by a (possibly empty) subordinating conjunction.

My question is, can SBAR be the first tag of a sentence? 
This doesn't make sense to me, but is the result of running python *stat_parser* parser on the sentence: *"I will say that I will send him mail tomorrow"*.

[image]